# Apache Jena interprets long as int

Tags: jena

I define a dataproperty assertion in Jena (version 3.0.0) by using

```
Long longValue=1L;
Model m = virtualDataset.getNamedModel(iri); //loading from Virtuoso  
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, m);
model.addLiteral(subject, model.getProperty(datapropertyIRI), ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral(longValue.toString(), XSDDatatype.XSDlong));
```

or by

```
model.addLiteral(subject, model.getProperty(datapropertyIRI), longValue);
```

Both approaches turn out to insert an integer value, instead. Where is my fault?

Additional info:

- I'm also using OpenLink Virtuoso through virt_jena 3 library.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - I get xsd:long in the output. https://gist.github.com/afs/784a757fea4bf10d984e5985da148593 I'm having to make assumptions about longValue. Is it a java.lang.Long? Could you provide a complete, minimal example please? What is the version number of Apache Jena that you are using?. `model.addLiteral(,,Object)` is not recommended.

Comment: I updated the question. Yes, its a java.lang.Long value; I'm using Jena 3 with the OpenLink Virtuoso Jena library, same version.

Comment: Did you try the gist?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: The link in the first the comment is to a complete example that is my production of the report. It uses a Jena memory model. It works - the output is ^^xsd:long. You didn't mention version but IIRC this aspect of Jena has not changed. Please try the example in your system.

Comment: Virtuoso is a separate system. It is based on an SQL. Sometimes, the characteristics of SQL show though. Type narrowing based on value is something SQL tends to do. 6 can be an xsd:integer, or xsd:int (which did you mean?). Or it is storing values, not terms, not retaining the original datatype. Several system do this, it is not unique to Virtuoso.

Comment: I tried your example and it seems working. I tried my example without virtuoso, the value is serialed as integer. Jena is version 3.

Comment: I guess that the problem is with VirtDataSet class of virutoso bridge.